# Simplification for intializing strings in a vector by a default string

Tags: c++, string, vector, constructor, initialization

I want to store 50 strings in a vector and want to initialize each string with the same string literal `"default"`. What I have so far is that:

```
std::vector<std::string> str = { 
                                  "default", "default", "default", "default", "default",
                                  "default", "default", "default", "default", "default", 
                                  "default", "default", "default", "default", "default",
                                  "default", "default", "default", "default", "default",
                                  "default", "default", "default", "default", "default",
                                  "default", "default", "default", "default", "default",
                                  "default", "default", "default", "default", "default",
                                  "default", "default", "default", "default", "default",
                                  "default", "default", "default", "default", "default",
                                  "default", "default", "default", "default", "default",
                               };
```

But does the C++ syntax allow a simpler way without to having repeat the string literal?

I´ve tried to do it with a loop since two hours, but since I´m new to use `std::vector`, I don´t know how to assign a certain string by a string literal in a vector properly.

Thank you for your help.

All useful answers will get an upvote from me.

Comment: Have you looked at [vector constructors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write

```
std::vector<std::string> str( 50, "default" );
```

The class template std::vector as all standard sequence containers has the following constructor

```
vector(size_type n, const T& value, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```